# DOM edits out of order

Tags: javascript, variadic

I have a function that adds a form to my page:

```
var board = document.getElementById("board");

board.innerHTML += "<form id='" + arguments[0] + "'>";

for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    board.innerHTML += "<input type='";

    var variable = arguments[i];

    board.innerHTML += variable.val.constructor.name + "' name='";
    board.innerHTML += variable.name + "'";

    board.innerHTML += "></input>";
}

board.innerHTML += "</form>";

console.log(document.getElementById("board").innerHTML);
```

For each argument (besides the form's id), it adds an item to the form.

Inspecting the HTML resulting from this function, it appears that the loop is run after the line `board.innerHTML += "</form>"`.  `console.log` outputs the following:

`<form id="example_name"></form>Number' name='x'&gt`

What's the cause of this?  Are variadics executed asynchronously or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't append just part of an HTML element to the `innerHTML` value, because the browser *immediately* attempts to parse it and will ignore anything malformed.

Accumulate the content into a simple JavaScript variable and then set `.innerHTML` when you're done with the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

I would build the string and then add it to innerHTML.

```
var board = document.getElementById("board");
var html = '';

html += "<form id='" + arguments[0] + "'>";

for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    html += "<input type='";

    var variable = arguments[i];

    html += variable.val.constructor.name + "' name='";
    html += variable.name + "'";

    html += "></input>";
}
html += "</form>";
board.innerHTML += html;
```

Variables are not executed async but adding partial elements to the DOM will cause issues.